# Proper dataset format for K-Means and DBSCAN clusterers

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, dbscan

I'm trying to classify web traffic using clustering algorithms with my own C program, capturing packets with `libpcap`.
In [this](http://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2006/papers/minenet-01.pdf) article K-Means, DBSCAN and AutoClass algorithms were used to classify web traffic.

I tested my dataset with different implementations of K-Means and DBSCAN, yet it is unclear to me how these two algorithms deal with data:

in K-Means from a [C clustering library](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm), the dataset is a matrix of `double**` where the rows are the points of observation and the columns are the features; this data struct suits me fine, in my code every row is a connection and every column is a feature (delay, or average dimension, or bps, ...) of it;

in DBSCAN from a [git repo](https://github.com/siddharth-agrawal/DBSCAN) the dataset is an `int **` matrix;

in another DBSCAN [repo](https://github.com/gyaikhom/dbscan) there is no matrix of features like above, but a linked list of `struct point` with `double x, y` coordinates.

I'm confused about the dataset representation: in my program, for every connection (row) there are a number of features (columns), but this representation seems to not agree with a linked list of points like in the second implementation of DBSCAN: should I convert the K-Means dataset implemented as a matrix in a linked list of `struct point` for DBSCAN?

I know this seems a CodeReview question but I want to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k-means needs to compute *means*.

Therefore, it only works on a *vector space*.

DBSCAN (see Generalized DBSCAN) needs:

- a neighborhood query (typically radius based but can be anything)
- a decision if a point is "core point" or not (typically based on the number of neighbors)

it is thus much more general. The implemetations you looked at probably were not very good.

Comment: So I can picture my K-Means nxm matrix as a DBSCAN set of n points with m dimensions each?

Comment: K-Means expects a nxm matrix. DBSCAN does not: it could process e.g. polygons, or CAD objects, or images, or audio signals, or text, or a graph, or ... if you you Euclidean distance, it will of course work with a nxm matrix, too.